# How can I use tFileExist component in Talend?

Tags: talend

Using Talend, I want to verify if there is a file named `ListePS.xls` in my `D:/`
to do some treatment else nothing.

How do I check if file exists in Talend?

Answer (score 11):

you must use the component **tFileExist** with two outputs  IF:

```
 ((Boolean) globalMap.get ("tFileExist_1_EXISTS")) for the case 1(File existence)
 ! ((Boolean) globalMap.get ("tFileExist_1_EXISTS")) for case 2 (non-existence of file)
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to verify that a file exists, you can use the **tFileExist** component and connect to your conditional treatment with a **Run If** link.
For parameterization details and usage examples, you can consult the Talend documentation, available in your installation.
In the Talend menubar, select **Help > Help contents** and then **Talend User Documentation > Integration components > tFileExists**.

[talend](/questions/tagged/talend)

Answer (score 7):

Design job like below

```
tFileExist----If(Exist)-------Use other Components 
        \
         \
          If(Not Exist) add other flow
```

Add below code in first IF condition `((Boolean) globalMap.get ("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))` and in second IF condition will be `!((Boolean) globalMap.get ("tFileExist_1_EXISTS"))` .